How to make the HTML file access an external JS file but the user acees the file by typing the url
I need to make my login javascript file to be external but I don't want people to see it since it is a login system and the file contains the username and password
I was thinking about giving a 403 HTTP Error when it gets accessed but the HTML won't be able to access it
I use the following code to test the thing:
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var filename = "." + q.pathname;
    var path = q.pathname
    if (filename === "./") {
      fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        console.log("filename: " + filename);
        console.log("q: " + q);
        return res.end();
      });
    }
    else {
      fs.readFile(filename + ".html", function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            console.log("filename: " + filename);
            console.log("q: " + q);
            return res.end("<h1>HTML ERROR</h1><p></p><strong>404 Not Found</strong><p></p><p>The requested page: \'" + path + ".html\' was not found</p>");
          }
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        console.log("filename: " + filename);
        console.log("Port: " + q.port)
        console.log("Hostname: " + q.hostname)
        console.log("Host: " + q.host)
        console.log("q: " + q);
      return res.end();
    });
  }
}).listen(8529);


It's normally suggested to create a backend when dealing with login logic to ensure that the user can't see it.

Anything that's executed in the browser can be seen by the user.

Authentication should be handled by the server side and not the client.  The HTML page you are displaying is hosted on a server. For my code.  I do it two way.  Host a login page via ASP.Net which is server based so nothing for the user to see code wise.  Or on Javascript pages I pass what the user has entered as a PW and user id to the server (via a webRequest) and return the users permissions, if any

I tried to use ASP .Net Web Pages, before, to make a simple form but it didn't worked with my  code, then I think JS is better

@ArthurYoshikasuArakaki create a new question about the asp problem. This isn't the way to go about it. If you send js to the browser, people can see it.
